# PHP order by upcoming dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `upevents` attributes in this table are:

1. Id
2. EventName
3. ArtistName
4. StartDate
5. EndDate

I need to select and display 3 events which dates will be the closest to today date.

For example today date is 3/8/2016, so i need to display 3rd,4th, and 5th.

> test date: 1st event start date -2/26/2015
>
> test date: 2nd event start date -2/25/2015
>
> test date: 3rd event start date -3/10/2016
>
> test date: 4th event start date -3/12/2016
>
> test date: 5th event start date -3/19/2016

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM upevents ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), 'StartDate')) LIMIT 3";
```

With the select query above it displays 1st,2nd, and 3rd.

Comment: And startDate > NOW(). To exclude past events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of quotes, now `StartDate` is interpreted as a string value.

You need:

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM upevents ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `StartDate`)) LIMIT 3";
                                                             ^  here   ^
```

Although you don't need to quote the column name here as it is not a reserved word.

Comment: And startDate > NOW(). To exclude past events.

Comment: I'm not sure thats what the OP wants @SirajulHaq , he asked for the 3 closest events.

Comment: @sagi He wants to get future events and he is getting past event as well, so to exclude past events need to Add WHERE StartDate > NOW().

Comment: How did you figure out the he want future events and not past events

Comment: For example today date is 3/8/2016, so i need to display 3rd,4th, and 5th.

Comment: @sagi I think he worked it out because the title of the question says 'upcoming'.